# Why I can't get correct answer in this regex?

Tags: python, regex

**Why I can't get correct answer in this regex?**

I wanted to get `Microsoft Edge` in `Unknown - abc - Microsoft Edge`

But I failed.

It only showed: `['- ', '- ']`, but not `Microsoft Edge`

Here is my code:

```
import re

content = 'Unknown - abc - Microsoft Edge'
p = re.compile(r"- .*?")
print(p.findall(content))
```

Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: With your shown samples, try regex: `^(?:.*?-){2}\s(.*)$` with link: https://regex101.com/r/WzHFqa/1 for Online demo of regex.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can use: `re.findall(r'.*-\s*(.+)', content)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `rplit` in this particular case (`content.rsplit('- ', 1)[-1]`), however if you insist on a regex, you can use:

```
p = re.compile(r"(?<=- )[^-]*$")  # non "-" after "- "
print(p.findall(content))
```

or

```
p = re.compile(r"(?<=- )(?:(?!- ).)*$")  # anything after "- " but not containing "- "
print(p.findall(content))
```

output: `['Microsoft Edge']`

Answer (score 1):

You get 2 times `-`  as a result because the pattern `- .*?` has a non greedy part at the end `.*?` that matches any character as few as possible.

As there are no rules following this part of the pattern, the engine can settle for matching zero characters, leaving just `-`  as a match.

To get the Microsoft Edge part, you can use a capture group:

```
-\s*([^-]+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `-\s*` Match `-` and optional whitespace chars
- `([^-]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars other than `-`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nk96Zp/1).

```
import re

s = "Unknown - abc - Microsoft Edge"
pattern = r"-\s*([^-]+)$"
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['Microsoft Edge']
```

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing what other input values are possible and what other contents should/shouldn't be matched, it is hard to design this.  p = re.compile(r"[^ ]* [^ ]*$") could work.